# Why does object.eval() work, square brackets return undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, eval

I am attempting to write a script that takes the method (in the form of a string) from the first column of a table, and shows the output of said method in the third column of each row. ex. Row 1 column 1 of an html table contains .getFullYear(), so in column 3 I want to run (my Date object) now.getFullYear(). In the next row, I will run now.getMonth() and so on.

When I run eval("now."+method) it runs without issue, but I'm trying to avoid using eval(). When I run now[method] the output returns undefined. Why does eval() work but now[method] return something different?

```JavaScript`

```
const now = new Date();
//gets the full table data
const methodTable = document.querySelector("#methods-table");

function tableTimeData(table) {
    const tableLength = table.rows.length;
    for (let i = 1; i < tableLength; i++) { //iterate through each table row, skipping the header
        let row = table.rows[i];
        let method = row.cells[0].innerText;
        row.cells[2].innerText = eval("now." + method);
        //OR
        method = method.substr(1);
        row.cells[2].innerText = now[method];
    }
}

tableTimeData(methodTable);
```

`HTML`

```
   <table class="table" id="methods-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Method Name</th>
                    <th>Method Description</th>
                    <th>Method Output</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getFullYear()</td>
                    <td>Returns the full 4 digit year.</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getMonth()</td>
                    <td>Returns the month as an integer (0-11).</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getDay()</td>
                    <td>Returns the day of the week as an integer (0-6).</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getHours()</td>
                    <td>Returns the hour as of creation.</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getMinutes()</td>
                    <td>Returns minute as of creation</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getSeconds()</td>
                    <td>Returns second as of creation</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.getTime()</td>
                    <td>Returns the number of miliseconds passed since Jan. 1 1970. Used as a baseline to compare 2 dates.</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.toDateString()</td>
                    <td>Returns a shortened date with day, month, date and year with day and month as names rather than integers.</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.toTimeString()</td>
                    <td>Returns a shortened time of day with hour, minute second and time zone (always Greenwhich Mean Time as a standard).</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-info font-weight-bold">.toLocaleString()</td>
                    <td>Returns a shortened time of day with hour, minute second and time zone (as your local time zone).</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I expect the result of eval("now."+method) to be the same as now[method].

Comment: what is the exact value of `method` (before you remove the first character for some reason)

Comment: No. `now.0` is not the same as `now["0"]`, `now.call()` is not the same as `now["call()"]`.

Comment: The first value of method is .getFullYear(). I remove the first character so that it no longer contains the "." as they are unnecessary with the square brackets. As indicated below, I also needed to remove the "()" at the end and add them after the square brackets for the code to operate correctly.

Comment: *The first value of method is .getFullYear(). I remove the first character so that it no longer contains the "." as they are unnecessary with the square brackets* If that were the case, wouldn't `eval("now." + method);` become `eval("now..getFullYear()");` because you removed it  only after `eval`

Comment: @TheMaster you are correct, I placed that code back in for comparison, however the first time I ran it I was not placing the "." at the end of "now. So it should read eval("now"+method); to run correctly. I was however able to get this to operate with the square brackets by removing the "." and the "()" at the end of .getFullYear. now[method](); is the solution I went with, with method = getFullYear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `method` is `.getFullYear()`, then

```
method = method.slice(1, -2);
row.cells[2].innerText = now[method]();
```

should work. You forgot to remove `()` from `method`

Comment: We don't know how exactly the OP was storing the `method` in the table (including whether it included the `.` and parentheses). But they were certainly missing the parentheses to call `now[method]`, which you have included.

Comment: Code now reads as suggested above and runs without issue. Thank you!

I was under the impression that the "()" for the arguments had to be included within the square brackets just as it does with .eval(). With them outside all code ran as intended.

Comment: @Erik Consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button on the answer.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, i was trying to figure how that was done.